# How to broadcast same messages to multiple interfaces in Mosca

Tags: node.js, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, mosca

I have 2 interfaces, one mqtt and one for websocket. I noticed if I have a backend, the mqtt does not route to websocket.

I created the mosca server as below:

```
server = new mosca.Server(
  {
    interfaces: 
    [
      { type: "mqtt", port: 1883 },
      {
        type: "mqtts",
        port: 8443,
        credentials: { keyPath: SECURE_KEY, certPath: SECURE_CERT }
      },
      { type: "http", port: 4000, bundle: true }
    ],
    onQoS2publish: "noack", 
    logger: { name: 'MoscaServer', level: 'debug' },
    backend: {
      type: "mqtt",
      json: false,
      mqtt: require("mqtt"),
      key: filesys.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/private.key"),
      cert: filesys.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/cert.pem"),
      ca: filesys.readFileSync(__dirname + "/certs/rootCA.cer"),
      clientId: "randomClientId",
      port: 8883,
      host: "<aws IOT endpoint>.iot.<aws region>.amazonaws.com",
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      protocol: "mqtts"
    },
  }
);
```

What do I need to do to route between all the 3: mqtt, websocket and the backend?

Thanks!

Comment: It works for publish from local to AWS, but publish from AWS does not reach to local, which is strange.

Comment: A backend is not a bridge, it's for clustering mosca instances